# ajax POST returns 403 error - how to call php file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Wordpress template where I am trying to use ajax to run a php file.

So the code below runs when I submit a form. I want it to use the value from the form (drop-down), and send it to the PHP file, where I can use it to access an external API, and send the data back.

```
var qty = jQuery("#qty").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/myphpfile.php",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {qty: qty},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(r){
    jQuery('#results').html(data);
    jQuery('#myform')[0].reset();
}).fail(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in the console...

```
POST ...mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mychildtheme/myphpfile.php 403
```

What do I need to do to allow this to work?

Thanks

Comment: 403 [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) "[t]he server understood the request, but will not fulfill it." You're trying to access information you can't have. Since you seem to own the server, check what parameters the ajax request to myphpfile.php requires. Maybe the request missing an authorization header, who knows.

Comment: Remove the contentType field maybe

Comment: @weltschmerz how can I check this?

Comment: @Musa I tried, didn't work.

Comment: You should rather not be targeting your own script file via its URL directly, that is not how AJAX is supposed to be done in WP. You should register a proper AJAX action, and a callback function. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/, https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @CBroe So I have read in a few places. If I don't use wordpress actions and callbacks, are there any security implications?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with the data on the receiving end.